# Normalization of a database when a row is an element of a tree

Tags: mysql, database, normalization, 3nf

I have a MySQL table that represents an element which is a node of a tree. The element has an ID, and a parent_id element, which refers to another element in the same table (can be null for top level elements). I wish to be able to sort these elements, both locally (elements which have the same parent), and globally (I want to flatten the tree and present it as a list). I have given each element a local_sorting_key, which can sort the elements within a parent node, but I want the ability to recursively sort the whole tree.

What I've done is add a new field, global_sorting_key, which is a concatenation of the global_sorting_key of the parent (if the element has a parent), and the local_sorting_key. This allows me to recursively set a sorting key for each element, and easily get the whole table and use SQL to sort it. However, this solution is not normalized, as changes to the local_sorting_key do not produce changes in the global_sorting_key, leading to internal inconsistencies.

How do I solve my problem in a simple way, while also maintaining 3NF?

Comment: You are describing the "adjacency list" model of storing hierarchical data, which (as you have found) requires data to be read recursively.  Since MySQL does not support recursive functions (unlike other RDBMS), you must either explicitly self-join the table multiple times (only works if you know the maximum recursion depth, and that depth is relatively low) or consider shifting to an alternative model that does not require recursion (such as "nested sets" or "transitive closures").

Comment: I am not against changing the whole table structure to accommodate a normalized hierarchical model. I insisted to the bosses that a flat model would serve just as well, and would be far simpler. But they put their foot down, and now I am wasting days trying to get this thing to work. I bet that in the end, I will eventually use a flat mode.